# Sets and expectations

Tags: expectation, sampling

Imagine two sets $A = \{1, 2, \dots, a\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3, \dots, b\}$ with $a \leq b$.
Let $f$ be a uniformly independently distributed random map $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $F = \bigcup_{i=1}^a f_{i}$

If I pick different functions $f$ until I find one such that $|A| = |F|$ what is the expected number of functions I pick? What is the probability that none of the $p$ functions I pick first results in $|A| = |F|$?

This looks like a sampling problem? How to think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ denote the set of functions such that $|F|=a$. Since $|G|=b!/(b-a)!$, 
the event that a function is in $G$ has probability 
$$
q=\frac{b!}{(b-a)!b^a}.
$$
The rank $N$ of the first function in $G$ is such that $P[N=n]=(1-q)^{n-1}q$, thus, $P[N\gt n]=(1-q)^n$, for every $n\geqslant1$.

Let $M$ denote the random set of the different functions not in $G$ picked before the first one in $G$. Any given function not in $G$ is in $M$ if and only if it was picked before any of the $|G|$ functions in $G$. This happens with probability $1/(|G|+1)$ and there are $b^a-|G|$ functions not in $G$, hence the expected size of $M$ is $(b^a-|G|)/(|G|+1)$. Thus, 
$$
E[|M|]=\frac{1-q}{b^{-a}+q}.
$$
**Edit:** A new question asked in the comments is to compute $E[|F|]$. This can be done using the trick of evaluating the probability, for any given $f$, to be in $F$. Rather, the probability that $f$ is not in $F$ is $(1-b^{-a})^a$ hence
$$
E[|F|]=\sum_fP[f\in F]=b^a(1-(1-b^{-a})^a).
$$

Comment: Why is $q=\frac{b!}{(b-a)!b^{a}}$?

Comment: Because b!/(b-a)! is the number of ways of choosing one by one a distinct elements in B, and b^a is the total number of ways of choosing one by one a elements, distinct or not, in B.

Comment: To compute the expected value do I sum over all possible functions $\sum_{i=1}^{b^{a}}$? So I end up with a series with no closed form?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: Makes sense. The expected value of $|F|$ would then be $q|G|+(1-q)|R|$ where $R$ is the set of functions such that $|F|<a$? Would |R| be $b^{a}-|G|$?

Comment: "The expected value of |F| would then be q|G|+(1−q)|R|" I really fail to see why this would be.

Comment: Would I have then to compute the probabilities that $|F|=1,|F|=2,...,|F|=a$ and sum over all possibilities?

Comment: See Edit. (But please, do not ask new questions in comments.)

Comment: Apologies. Thought I could generalize your earlier reasoning. Your answer is correct